# URL 301 rewrite with mod_rewrite if contains variable ?tag=xxx

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, http-status-code-301

I just can't seem to be able to run a 301 redirect and rewrite when a specific variable is somewhere inside a dynamic URL.

For example, with any of these URLs:

```
/movabletype/mt-search.cgi?tag=SOMETHING&limit=20
/some-other-random-content?post=somethinghere&tag=SOMETHING
```

If **`tag=SOMETHING`** is anywhere inside the URL, then redirect to:
**`/categories/something_here/`**

Any ideas?!  Here's what I have so far - I'm at a loss as to what to put inside the RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule tag=SOMETHING /categories/something_here/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite condition requires a left- and right-hand argument. It looks like you want to redirect when a certain URL parameter is present (i.e, tag), so you can use `%{QUERY_STRING}` in your condition.

Consider the following example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=([A-Za-z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /categories/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should take a URL like `/some-other-random-content?post=somethinghere&tag=SOMETHING` and redirect it to `/categories/SOMETHING`.

[URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) may be a helpful guide.